# Woocommerce : Add Body class to product page if the current product is in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found this great snippet from here https://gist.github.com/michaelbourne/a2fbebbc839a41c4204524fcd020061e

The following is the function to add a body class to the Woocomerce product page if the cart contains any product.

```
    <?php

// Add a body class via the body_class filter in WP
// =============================================================================
add_filter( 'body_class', 'mb_body_class_for_cart_items' );
function mb_body_class_for_cart_items( $classes ) {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        $classes[] = 'cart-has-items';
    }
    return $classes;
}

// Add a body class via javascript for AJAX enabled sites
// =============================================================================
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mb_body_class_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function mb_body_class_for_ajax_add_to_cart() {
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
      $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        if( ! $(this).hasClass('cart-has-items') ){
          $(this).addClass('cart-has-items');
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
<?php
}
```

Does anyone know how to modify the above code snippet to add a class to the body of the product page when the cart contains the current product?

For example, if 'item A' is in the cart, when a visitor browses the 'item A' product page it should contain body class 'already-added'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function that you can use multiple times. This function can be used for both variable and simple products:

```
function ywp_check_product_is_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $cart_item_ids = array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] );

            if( in_array( $product_id, $cart_item_ids ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'ywp_body_class_for_cart_items' );
function ywp_body_class_for_cart_items( $classes ) {
    // Check user currently is in product page
    if( ! is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    if( ywp_check_product_is_in_cart( get_the_id() ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'already-added';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` of your actiive theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks but this breaks the site showing a blank page. In source I can see there is an opening body tag '<body ' and nothing after that

Comment: You're welcome. Please delete your code and copy/paste my code exactly the same way. The code is tested and works.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted my code and copy/paste your code. the result is the same. Blank white page with just an opening body tag . Can I paste the webpage URL here?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the code you used. Thanks

Comment: Code https://snipboard.io/HFrSLi.jpg   Result https://snipboard.io/678j3f.jpg

Comment: I guessed :) you did not add the function `ywp_check_product_is_in_cart`, you have to add both blocks of code I wrote

Comment: ops! my mistake! I only added e code below 'Usage'. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much, Do you mind if I ask if these code snippets would have any impact on site performance/speed?  I also added the following code to address Ajax enabled pages.                                      
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
      $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        if( ! $(this).hasClass('cart-has-item') ){
          $(this).addClass('cart-has-item');
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

Comment: You're welcome. How much it affects performance depends on the number of products in the cart, but normally it has so little effect that it is not visible.